# Xcode C Preprocessor Error

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

In my project i use multiple environments ([see more](http://www.blackdogfoundry.com/blog/migrating-ios-app-through-multiple-environments/)) and after Xcode update to 6.3 version i faced with the problem that project stopped to build and returned an error

```
fatal error: 'environment_preprocess.h' file not found

In file included from <built-in>

'environment_preprocess.h' file not found in /%project_name%/<command line>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found a solution, to fix that issue you need:

In left Navigator menu, open the first tab "Project navigator" and select your project

Open Build Settings

In finder input paste the text – "environment_preprocess"

After that you see "Info.plist Preprocessor Prefix File" title and value "environment_preprocess", to fix problem you need add folder and slash. Exapmle if my app folder named "PDD" the value text must be **"PDD/environment_preprocess"**